Why a Compile Error Occurs When Printing the Address of s[3]
I have a question about this code:
char s[8] = "Basic-C";
char* p;

p = s;//p=s[0];
printf("s[3]==>%c\n", &s[3]);

The compile error happens when I print the single character through the s[3] address.
Please explain so I can understand.

The confusion might come from the fact that scanf needs an &, but printf does not.

@BoP scanf !!?? where did that come from?

@4386427 - I bet the OP hasn't invented &s[3] themselves, but seen it used with scanf, and then assumed printf works just the same.

@BoP the other way round is even more, they omit & with scanf because they assume it works just like with printf.

I guess you get an error message like this:
warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *'

for this line:
printf("s[3]==>%c\n", &s[3]);

&s[3] is the memory address of s[3] but you probably want to print the third character of the s string.
You probably want this:
printf("s[3]==>%c\n", s[3]);

which will show following output:
s[3]==>i


Or maybe you actually want to print the address of s[3] (this is not quite clear in the question), then you need to use the %p format specifier:
printf("s[3]==>%p\n", (void*)&s[3]);

which will give an output which may look like this:
s[3]==>0000000D1F4FF92B

The reason why the (void*) cast in (void*)&s[3] is necessary is explained here.
